# Codeigniter "form_open($login_user, $attributes)" is giving error

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

there is issue in in issue in in "form_open()" function i giving you guys a image of error

[image]

```
<?php $attributes = array('id' => 'login_form','class' => 'form_horizontal'); ?>

<?= form_open($login_user, $attributes); ?>

<?= form_close(); ?>
```

There is new error after that 
[image]

Issue is SOLVED

Comment: what is inside $login_user .it's action url?

Comment: whats inside `$login_user` ??

Comment: also verify $this->load->helper('form'); added in your controller

Comment: $data['login_user'] = 'users/login_view';

Comment: just write `form_open('users/login_view')` and check function is loading

Comment: site loads without `index.php` ??

Comment: OK @AbdullaNilam

Comment: If you did solve your issue yourself, please consider answering your own question. Provide details of how you solved it and mark it as answered. Maybe this will help other people in the future.